# Attaching File To Microsoft Outlook with AppleScript

Tags: outlook, applescript

I am trying to make a script that will attach a file to Outlook and then send it. I have that part of the script down fine. My only problem is that for some reason the file isn't attaching. When I look at the replies box at the bottom, it says that it attached and sent the email successfully, however, the file is not attached. What is wrong with my script?

```
tell write_email
    delay 1
    make new attachment with properties {file:fileAttachment}
    delay 1
end tell
send write_email
```

I already defined prior to that bit of code this:

```
    set fileAttachment to /Desktop/file-name
```

Comment: have you tried a Mac colon-separated style file path? Like "StartupDrive:folder:otherfolder:file"?

Comment: That doesn't work either. I tried: ":Desktop:file-name" and it produced the same result as with slashes

Comment: File property of attachment should be a 'file" class, not a 'string' containing path of the file. correct form should be {file: ("Users:myUser:Desktop:my file" as alias) }

Comment: I tried that, but it says "Script Error. Can't make {file:"Users:username:Desktop:file name"} into type alias

Comment: If that's the case, try `alias "Users:username:Desktop:file name"` or `"Users:username:Desktop:file name" as alias` (but the file had better be there)

Comment: Now I am getting the error: "Finder got an error: Can't get alias \"/Users/\". number -1728. i can't quite understand why my script isn't working.